# Silverstripe create a better LimitWordCount function

Tags: silverstripe, strip

The framework offer LimitWordCount in StringField.php file. It's great but not totally perfect. Some tags et ponctuation needs the be corrected.
I would like :

- Keep tags `<sup><sub><em>`
- Correct ponctuation : «.» to «. », «,» to «, », «?» to «? » etc....

I have made my own LimitWordCount :

```
public function MyLimitWordCount($int) {

    $text = strip_tags($this->owner->value, '<sup><sub><em>');

     if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $int) {

          $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
          $pos = array_keys($words);
          $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$int]) . '…';
     }

    $text = str_replace('.', '. ', $text );
    $text = str_replace('!', '! ', $text );
    $text = str_replace('…', '… ', $text );
    $text = str_replace('?', '? ', $text );

    return $text;

}
```

That not works totally. Some ponctuation are not corrected and video shortcodes `[embed width="480...]` made in an HTMLEditor fields are keep with my function. I dont' know what him doing wrong.

Comment: What version of SilverStripe are you using, 3 or 4?

Comment: I'm using SilverStripe 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll continue to get the shortcodes in your text becuase you need to parse them first.

This is most easily resolved by using `(string)$this->owner->dbObject('value')` rather than `$this->owner->value`.

You can then manipulate the value where the shortcodes have been expanded.

I can't comment on why your punctuation is not being "corrected" in this instance as you haven't supplied much information on which punctuation and under what circumstances it isn't working.